# Download Orion Broker Public Image from Fiware Lab

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, filab

I wonder if there is any way to download a public image (e.g. orion-psb-image-R4.1) from Fiware Lab to install on a local VM?

How is the procedure performed?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: This should be explained in the README.md in orion's github repo.

Comment: Maybe @flopez can help

Comment: @kzangeli There is not. I've looked at all the documentation, nothing about it is treated.

Comment: @flopez Can you tell me something about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the following link.

- [Locally run a FIWARE Lab Instance In another Hypervisors](https://www.slideshare.net/joseignaciocarretero/locally-run-a-fiware-lab-instance-in-another-hypervisors)
  (José Ignacio Carretero Guarde, FIWARE Cloud and Platform Expert)

Comment: Hi @fisuda,

Following the link you passed, make sure the default version of Python is 2.6.6. Install 2.7 as well as the others.

But when you run the commands with virtualenv gives error. Make sure that even with the installation of Python 2.7, everything runs from Python 2.6.6 (default) and so the errors.

Is there any way to execute commands using python 2.7 installed?

Comment: It seems that your question is about switching a default version from python 2.6 to 2.7. I'm not a python expert. You should search FAQs or make a new question with tag 'python' on the stackoverflow.

Comment: Hi @fisuda, have you done this process of downloading an image from Fiware Lab?

Comment: Yes. And, I wrote the following articles.
[https://www.letsfiware.jp/fiware-lab-cloud-openstack-glance-fiware-images/](https://www.letsfiware.jp/fiware-lab-cloud-openstack-glance-fiware-images/),
[https://www.letsfiware.jp/fiware-lab-cloud-image-vmware-esxi/](https://www.letsfiware.jp/fiware-lab-cloud-image-vmware-esxi/)
They are written in Japanase. You  should use the Google Translate. You can find a button of Google Translate at the botom of the article.